# validate and saving an array of objects laravel 6, vue, axios

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js, axios

vue function:

```
        sendData() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        const postData = {
            data: this.items,

        };
        var self = this;
        axios.post(this.postUrl, postData).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);

           self.isLoading = false;
        });

        this.items = [];
    },
```

Laravel controller:

```
    public function store(request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->data as $data) {

        $serie = [];

        $serie = ['imei' => $data['serie']];

        $imei = new Imei([
            'imei' => $data['serie'],
            'status_id' => 1,
            'sucursal_id' => $data['sucursal'],
            'equipo_id' => $data['equipo']

        ]);

        $validator = Validator::make($serie, [
            'imei' => 'unique:imeis,imei|digits:15',



        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
```

`// Here I need to build the response of every imei with its validation error`

```
        } else {

            $imei->save();


        }


    }


    return >Here I want to return the errors back to vue 
}
```

my vue app sends to laravel trough axios an array of objects that looks like this [{imei:xxxx,sucursal_id...},{imei:xxxx,sucursal_id...}]  I need to validate imei is unique and save it, and if error return errors in the same way [{imei:xxxx,errorMsg: 'already exist in DB'}]. but I can't find the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to customize your errorbag right  ? try this one out. Add this inside your fail condition. Let me know if it works.

```
$err = [{imei:xxxx,errorMsg: 'already exist in DB'}]; 

foreach ($validator->errors()->toArray() as $error)  {
    foreach($error as $sub_error) {
           array_push($err, $sub_error);
        }
  }
return ['errors'=>$err];
```